# Rails Encrypt POST Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have an SSL enabled on site , And added force_ssl :true to my production.rb file

But when I Submit a Form the Post Params can be seen as Plain Text .

Did I miss something ?

How do I encrypt the Post Params Such that it can't be Tampered .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this Using Cookies by signing them.

P.S Previously I was able to get the params and edit them using Tamper Data